# Can I use an array of CSS psuedo-classes in a LESS mixin?

Tags: css, css-selectors, less, pseudo-class

I'm starting to use the LESS framework for styles in an app. I often have places in the app where I need to standardize pseudo-classes for an element to all be the same styles.

Rather than typing out

`button:hover,
button:active,
button:hover:active {
    /*styles here */
}`

I'm using LESS's nested styles to append those psuedo-classes like so:

```
.button {
 {
    &,
    &:hover,
    &:active,
    &:hover:active {
            border: 2px solid #000000
    }
}
```

That works perfectly fine and outputs button class with appended psuedo-classes.

My question is this: Can I take this even a step further to add the psuedo calls into a mixin and therefore call the mixin? I know this might seem like over-engineering, but I'm reusing this alot throughout several stylesheets and it would be great to be able to reuse one line of code with a mix in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use functional mixins:

```
.button(@_arg) {
    &,
    &:hover,
    &:active,
    &:hover:active {
            border: @_arg;
    }
}
```

and then use it following way:

```
.example {
    .button(2px solid #000);
}
```